# cmd ftp mput - jpeg files differs from original file

Tags: batch-file, ftp, cmd, ftp-client

currently im executing this batch for ftp -s:

open 192.1.2.3
USER
PASSWORD
cd "folder"
lcd "c:\folder"
prompt
mkdir 20140730
cd "20140730"
mput *.jpeg
quit

During testing I was trying to mput like 10 files and everything seems fine. Now im transfering aprox. 1400 files with total size 700MB and my problem is that uploaded file is different then the original one. JPEG seems to be corrupted, on some image is lighter part another part is dark, or there are some coloured lines or parts on image... Is there way check if files moved by mput are same with source files? All files i have checked are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue the `binary` keyword in the script before transferring the files.

```
prompt
binary
```

The binary keyword stops files being truncated at the first EOF character, which is the default behaviour in text transfer mode.

Comment: Oh man, sad is that I knew it have to be binary to transfer jpeg, but I thought binary is default for the FTP I was testing on. Problem is that I have tested it with blank jpeg and some random dots placed. Data I'm uploading now are normal photos. Thanks for forcing me to add one line to the script.